# My python editor wrongly indenting all new lines

Tags: python-3.x, editor, indentation

```
def print_menu():
    print('1. Kilometers to Miles')
    print('2. Miles to Kilometers')
def km_mi():
    km=float(input('Enter distance in kilometers: ')
    mi= km/1.609
    print('Distance in miles: {}'.format(mi))
def mi_km():
            print('I suddenly started indenting way over here today...')
```

Why is it doing this? It happened to my teacher at the beginning of the semester and she never dealt with it so I assume I can't ask her. Help! I don't want to adjust every line of code forever and ever. I'm super new to any coding so sorry if this is something I should know.

Comment: One of your lines is missing a closing parenthesis, that's what's confusing your IDE.

Comment: I just figured out it isn't super indenting on new documents, so it's just this one--but I can't figure out why.

Comment: That seems unlikely, given that *I just told you precisely why*.

Comment: That did it! THANK YOU.

Comment: sry. My screen hadn't updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a missing parenthesis earlier in your code. Then your IDE thinks that the parentheses have not been closed and indents your lines.